# share data between widget blueprints

Tags: widget, unreal

I am trying to use binding created in one widget blueprint to use in another one.
what are the options I have.
I am using unreal 5.1

Thanks in advance.

Functional Blueprints is not accepting the node which was created by Binding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.